Robust or Stochastic Optimization Approach for Maximizing Profit with Limited Price Information
I am tackling a linear maximization problem where I need to select the optimal product among several options over a series of weeks, given certain constraints, in order to maximize future profit. The decision variables are binary, indicating whether or not a particular product is chosen.
The objective function is expressed as:
$$
\max_{j} \sum_{i} choice(j) \cdot c_{i,j}^T p_{i,j}$$
Where:
$c_{i,j}$ represents the production quantity of product $j$ in week $i$,
$p_{i,j}$ represents the price of product $j$ in week $i$,
$choice(j)$ is a binary variable indicating the selection of product $j$, and The summation is over all weeks $i$.
However, I encounter a challenge because $p_{i,j}$ is not fully known. It is a time series, and I lack future values as well as extensive historical data. To address this issue, I'm considering either Robust Optimization or Stochastic Optimization techniques. Which approach should I pursue, and how can I implement it effectively to maximize profit in this scenario?

This question may get better answers at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Another alternative site is https://or.stackexchange.com/  If you want, we can migrate it for you! But tell us which

Yes, i would like to migrate it to  or.stackexchange.com, Thanks an dsorry for my late response.
